# Notification image never displays in Android

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

If suppose I create Notification icons by uploading a png image using Image Asset tool from Android Studio by choosing type as notification would it generate all required icons with the dimensions as needed by notification icon spec? if Yes, then there should not be any problem displaying this icon in the notification bar, isn't it? hmm it doesn't in my case but rather it shows the default App icon no matter what. Below is my code. Any guess why its failing, perhaps this is just a cosmetic issue through.

```
      NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("VEDRISE",
          "Vedic Notifications",
          NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("Will display daily Panchang notificatons");
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
      }
      Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
//      URL url = new //URL("https://66.media.tumblr.com/ec76b7d7e0529af6e3a437edb6c6c255/tumblr_phiur//jqePq1xp0noco1_75sq.png");
 //     Bitmap image = //BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
      NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "VEDRISE")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sunrise) // notification icon
  //      .setLargeIcon(image)
        .setContentTitle(title) // title for notification
        .setContentText(content)// message for notification
        .setSound(alarmSound) // set alarm sound for notification
        .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, this.getClass());
      PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
      int id = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
      Log.d("VedicHoroo", String.format("id: %d", id));
      mNotificationManager.notify( id, mBuilder.build());
```

Just to give you some scope, this requirement is for local notification which will trigger by the AlarmReceiver. The receiver is triggered by Alarm without issues but the Notification does not display image which is set by setSmallIcon instead it display only the App Icon

Answer (score 2):

```
  Notification notification  = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND|Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS|Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
```

Even if ic_notification is transparant and white. It must be also defined in the Manifest meta data, like so:

```
         <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"

    android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
```

add this line in the manifest.xml file in application block

Comment: this did not work for me, the manifest setting you suggest looks like for firebase notifications, but I am not using push notification, its a local notification the daily alarm should trigger